# How to update an Array of Objects field in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a data structure, like so

```js
{
  _id: '',
  name: 'A',
  financialReports: {
    monthlyBill: 20,
    monthlyBillReports: [
      {
        month: 'JAN',
        isPaid: true
      },
      {
        month: 'FEB',
        isPaid: false
      },
      {
        month: 'MAR',
        isPaid: false
      },
      {
        month: 'APR',
        isPaid: false
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
},
...
```

How should I dynamically update `financialReports.monthlyBillReports[i].isPaid` to true? I got array of data that indicate to month field in Database from front-end `['FEB', 'APR']`, But I am not sure if I could iterate over the array and make update query to Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a loop something like:

```
let yourArray = ['FEB', 'APR'] // just mocking the array

yourArray.forEach((mo)=>{
      collectionName.findOneAndUpdate( 
             {_id: 'document id goes here'},
             { '$set': {'financialReports.monthlyBillReports.$[frFilter].isPaid': true}},
             { arrayFilters: [ {frFilter.month: mo} ], multi: true}
          ).then(
                //do whatever you need here
          )
    })
```

or in a more straight forward manner:

```
collectionName.findOneAndUpdate( 
                 {_id: 'document id goes here'},
                 { '$set': {'financialReports.monthlyBillReports.$[frFilter].isPaid': true}},
                 {arrayFilters: [ {frFilter.month: {$in: yourArray} } ], multi: true}
              ).then(
                    //do whatever you need here
              )
```

Comment: It works but instead of changing ```isPaid``` to ```true``` It writes a new ```isPaid: true``` So i got two isPaid which have value false and true respectively, How to fix this ? thank you for your help by the way

Comment: sorry, ive edited the code. there was a space between  $[frFilter]. and isPaid, ive removed that. just make sure remove the other isPaid fields first, before running it again

Comment: and oh, should be financialReports.monthlyBillReports.$[frFilter] instead

Comment: why you dont go with `updateMany` and filter it like this `arrayFilters: [ {frFilter.month: { $in: ["FEB", "APR"] }} ]` so you dont need to go with a forEach

Comment: that will work too  arrayFilters: [ {frFilter.month: {$in: yourArray} } ], i think there is no need for updateMany as it only affects one document